# Idle AWS EC2 but high memory usage

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, memory-usage, memory-leak

I'm using Amazon EC2 instance **[C4.large](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/)**, total 3.75G memory, running Amazon-Linux-2015-09-HVM

The memory usage increases day by day, like there's a memory leak. Then I kill all my program and all memory hog processes like `Nginx/PHP-FPM/Redis/MySQL/sendmail`. It's very strange the memory is not released, still very high.
The line `-/+ buffers/cache:       3070        696` indicates actual free memory with buffer/cache excluded:

```
$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3767       3412        354          4        138        203
-/+ buffers/cache:       3070        696
Swap:            0          0          0
```

As you can see after kill there are only a few user processes running, the highest is only 0.1% memory usage:

```
$ ps aux --sort=-resident|head -30
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root     32397  0.0  0.1 114232  6672 ?        Ss   08:04   0:00 sshd: ec2-user [priv]
ec2-user 32399  0.0  0.1 114232  4032 ?        S    08:04   0:00 sshd: ec2-user@pts/0
ntp       2329  0.0  0.1  23788  4020 ?        Ss   Dec06   0:00 ntpd -u ntp:ntp -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -g
ec2-user 32400  0.0  0.0 113572  3368 pts/0    Ss   08:04   0:00 -bash
rpcuser   2137  0.0  0.0  39828  3148 ?        Ss   Dec06   0:00 rpc.statd
root      2303  0.0  0.0  76324  2944 ?        Ss   Dec06   0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd
root      2089  0.0  0.0 247360  2676 ?        Sl   Dec06   0:00 /sbin/rsyslogd -i /var/run/syslogd.pid -c 5
root      1545  0.0  0.0  11364  2556 ?        Ss   Dec06   0:00 /sbin/udevd -d
root         1  0.0  0.0  19620  2540 ?        Ss   Dec06   0:00 /sbin/init
ec2-user  1228  0.0  0.0 117152  2480 pts/0    R+   10:32   0:00 ps aux --sort=-resident
root      2030  0.0  0.0   9336  2264 ?        Ss   Dec06   0:00 /sbin/dhclient -q -lf /var/lib/dhclient/dhclient-eth0.leases -pf /var/run/dhclient-eth0.pid eth0
rpc       2120  0.0  0.0  35260  2264 ?        Ss   Dec06   0:00 rpcbind
root      2071  0.0  0.0 112040  2116 ?        S<sl Dec06   0:00 auditd
root      1667  0.0  0.0  11308  2064 ?        S    Dec06   0:00 /sbin/udevd -d
root      1668  0.0  0.0  11308  2040 ?        S    Dec06   0:00 /sbin/udevd -d
root      2373  0.0  0.0 117608  2000 ?        Ss   Dec06   0:00 crond
ec2-user  1229  0.0  0.0 107912  1784 pts/0    S+   10:32   0:00 head -30
root      2100  0.0  0.0  13716  1624 ?        Ss   Dec06   0:09 irqbalance --pid=/var/run/irqbalance.pid
root      2432  0.0  0.0   4552  1580 ttyS0    Ss+  Dec06   0:00 /sbin/agetty ttyS0 9600 vt100-nav
root      2446  0.0  0.0   4316  1484 tty6     Ss+  Dec06   0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty6
root      2439  0.0  0.0   4316  1464 tty3     Ss+  Dec06   0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty3
root      2437  0.0  0.0   4316  1424 tty2     Ss+  Dec06   0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty2
root      2444  0.0  0.0   4316  1416 tty5     Ss+  Dec06   0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty5
root      2434  0.0  0.0   4316  1388 tty1     Ss+  Dec06   0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty1
root      2441  0.0  0.0   4316  1388 tty4     Ss+  Dec06   0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty4
dbus      2160  0.0  0.0  21768   232 ?        Ss   Dec06   0:00 dbus-daemon --system
root      2383  0.0  0.0  15372   144 ?        Ss   Dec06   0:00 /usr/sbin/atd
root      2106  0.0  0.0   4384    88 ?        Ss   Dec06   0:16 rngd --no-tpm=1 --quiet
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Dec06   0:00 [kthreadd]
```

No process using high memory but system total free is only 696M out of 3.75G, is it a bug of EC2 or Amazon Linux? I have another **[T2.micro](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/)** instance running, after kill `Nginx/MySQL/PHP-FPM` the memory is released and free number bumped. 
It's appreciated if someone could help.

Comment: System "available" memory is essentially 3070, of which 696 is completely free and would not need to be reclaimed from the cache.  I see nothing of concern, here.  Also, EC2 is a virtual machine environment, not an operating system, and as such it technically could not have a bug that caused system memory to leak.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. The 3070 is not 'available' since when around 500M left `mysql_safe` restarts itself

Comment: `egrep 'kernel|oom' /var/log/syslog`.  mysqld_safe is restarting mysql because the kernel is killing mysqld due to low memory.  It's probably dipping lower than what you see, but when mysqld gets killed, the real memory hog may also abruptly react to the loss of connection to mysql and release some of the memory it's hogging.  You should add a swap file so you can catch the hogs in action before they trigger such a reaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a C4.large instance handy to check my theory, so I may be shooting in the dark, but have you checked the stats for the Xen balloon driver?

Here's a dramatic explanation of the possible mechanism: http://lowendbox.com/blog/how-to-tell-your-xen-vps-is-overselling-memory/

And here's documentation of the various sysfs paths that will give you more information: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/stable/sysfs-devices-system-xen_memory

Comment: http://lowendbox.com/blog/how-to-tell-your-xen-vps-is-overselling-memory/ is a similar issue, idle instance but high memory. However C4.large with Amazon-Linux-HVM doesn't have Xen balloon, paths like /proc/xen/balloon, /sys/devices/system/xen_memory/ don't exist. I try `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` to free caches and free number decreases. Thanks for your answer however I don't get why killing processes doesn't affect free number.

Comment: The "lowendbox" author is grasping at straws and, in any event, AWS doesn't play oversubscription games like this. This is speculation, and does not apply here.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to identify what specific processes and commands are using it.

You can take a look at the memory section [here](https://rubytune.com/cheat)

**Start with this command**

```
ps aux --sort=-resident|head -11
```

Comment: Thanks for your attention. I've listed the output of `ps aux --sort=-resident`.
I killed most processes, now only a few system essentials are running, no process occupying large amount of memory. It's strange to me.

Answer (score 0):

I Think this link describes the "problem" you are seeing quite nicely

http://www.linuxatemyram.com/

The upshot, is that Linux is simply using as much memory as it can as a disk cache. Clearly this makes disk access quicker.

The moment that RAM is needed by a program (nginx for example) Then the RAM will be "deallocated" from caching duties, and allocated instead to whatever program you have run.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. I saw that article, and I'm just saying the line `-/+ buffers/cache:       3070        696` which indicated actually free memory already (buffer/cache excluded).